# Font issues while using doctype XHTML 1.0

Tags: jquery-ui, fonts, doctype, webfonts

I have a web application for my project and I am planning to upgrade it by using jquery in various areas.
I am using chosen.jquery.cs script for dropdown lists. However, I faced an issue wherein the contents of the page are getting mixed with the contents of dropdown upon expanding it. This issue got resolved when I changed the doctype from `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >` to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`. Unfortunately, this new doctype is not also perfect. With this doctype, fonts are not visible properly. Also, width of some textboxes has increased abruptly.
Being a new user on this forum I am unable to post the screenshots :(
Can anyone please provide a solution/alternative for this problem. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arpit

Comment: "fonts are not visible properly" is not much of a problem description. In what way are they not visible properly?

Answer (score 0):

By using the XHTML doctype instead of HTML 4 Transitional, you are forcing the browsers into "strict mode" instead of "[quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)", and that's a good thing.

However, it seems that your CSS was coded for quirks mode, so you are probably using the "[border-box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)" box model. You will have to rework your CSS code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I am using jQuery to apply css on the controls. However, the same jQuery code works fine with the HTML 4 doctype. Also, I am using XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype and not the strict one. Will it make any difference? I tried after changing to various modes of XHTML 1.0 doctype, but didnt get any positive result :(

Comment: Any XHTML doctype will force the browsers into strict mode. That's what you want, this way browsers will try to render your contents the same way. Your problem is not the doctype. I suggest you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the relevant parts of your code, then post it here so we can help you.